# Unity leaderboard on mac os x device - Pubnub, Playfab or Firebase?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, pubnub, playfab

I am currently making a a leaderboard feature for my Mac OS X Unity game. I first tried Playfab but I kept getting an error saying "PlayFabException: Must be logged in to call this method PlayFab". I can't find a way to resolve this.

I have 2 scripts that does this, this is the code for the PlayFabManger script:

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.ClientModels;
using System;

    public class PlayFabManager : MonoBehaviour

    //public static PlayFabManager instance;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //instance = this;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlayFabSettings.staticSettings.TitleId))
        {
            /*
            Please change the titleId below to your own titleId from PlayFab Game Manager.
            If you have already set the value in the Editor Extensions, this can be skipped.
            */
            PlayFabSettings.staticSettings.TitleId = "F9F3D";
        }
        Login();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void Login()
    {
        var request = new LoginWithCustomIDRequest
        {
            CustomId = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier,
            CreateAccount = true
        };
        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithCustomID(request, OnSuccess, OnError);
    }

    //private void OnLoginSuccess(LoginResult result)
    //{
    //    //>> Call Client API here <<
    //    var getStoreItemsRequest = new GetStoreItemsRequest { StoreId = "[YourStoreId]" };// Please change this value to your own storeId from PlayFab Game Manager
    //    PlayFabClientAPI.GetStoreItems(getStoreItemsRequest, OnGetSuccess, OnError);

    //}


    void OnSuccess(LoginResult result)
    {
        print("Successful login create");
    }

    public void SendLeaderBoard(int score)
    {
        var request = new UpdatePlayerStatisticsRequest
        {
            Statistics = new List<StatisticUpdate>
            {
                new StatisticUpdate
                {
                    StatisticName = "PlatformScore",
                    Value = score
                }
            }
        };
        PlayFabClientAPI.UpdatePlayerStatistics(request, OnLeaderboardUpdate, OnError);
    }

    void OnLeaderboardUpdate(UpdatePlayerStatisticsResult result)
    {
        print("Successful leaderboard sent");
    }

    void OnError(PlayFabError error)
    {
        print("Error while logging in/creating account!");
        print(error.GenerateErrorReport());
    }

    public void GetLeaderBoard()
    {
        var request = new GetLeaderboardRequest
        {
            StatisticName = "PlatformScore",
            StartPosition = 0,
            MaxResultsCount = 10
        };
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetLeaderboard(request, OnLeaderboardGet, OnError);
    }

    private void OnLeaderboardGet(GetLeaderboardResult result)
    {
        foreach (var item in result.Leaderboard)
        {
            print(item.Position + " " + item.PlayFabId + " " + item.StatValue);
        }
    }

    }
```

`

I also have a line of code in another script that is called at the start method and refers to the above script, where I pass in a Playerprefs.GetInt variable:
`playFabManager.SendLeaderBoard(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TtlPoints"));`

Does anyone have any idea on resolving this error? Is there an easier way to achieve this leaderboard feature on Mac OS X using other extensions such as firebase or pubnub?

Sorry for my English, looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: The question is vague. Do you have some code that's not working? Can you include it? What troubleshooting have you done. Is your cocoapods and podfile up-to-date? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Sorry for any inconvenience, I have attached the code now. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PubNub awesome, Beamable uses them for fabs leaderboards for Unity! Check them out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check this out if I can't find a solution to resolve the error in the PlayFab script

Comment: Just want to confirm: does PubNub support unity game in Mac OS X platform?

Comment: ✅ PubNub support unity game in Mac OS X platform - yes this is supported

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the Firebase answer.

If you go the Firebase route, there is not an out of the box Leaderboard solution. There is an [example open source repository](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/unity-solutions/tree/master/Firebase_Leaderboard) that you can use to implement leaderboards on Realtime Database that should be relatively simple to implement.

Your second problem is that although Realtime Database does work on desktop (and the leaderboard in particular hasn't given me any issues), [it is currently a *beta* feature only intended for use during development](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#desktop-workflow). If you file a related bug, the team will work to fix it, but it will probably be prioritized behind any mobile-features. You could implement it all using the [REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database) API directly, but at this point the official Unity samples and documentation won't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Call your `Login()` method by Invoke and set the time to 5 seconds.

It will hold the login for 5 seconds.

This error occurs when the `SendLeaderBoard` method is called before the `Login` method is called. You should try to call the `Login` method before the `SendLeaderBoard` method.